# Postgres replication is not working for base64 content

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-12

I'm using PostgreSQL 12. I have set up replication. And also set up the versioning history trigger for all the tables in the replica database to store audit history. But here in one of the tables, I'm storing the based64 content and it is not replicated properly in the replica database and it is stopping the database server.

It is throwing the error.

```
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

It is not happing in every case.

**Base64(XML) Content in Master Database**
[image]

**Base64(XML) Content(InValid Conent) in Replica Database**

[image]

Can anyone help me with why it is happening? Thanks in advance.

Below are the steps for configuration the replication:

**Publication Databaase:**

- Creating the `REPLICA IDENTITY and assigning it to each table
- Creating replication slot and publication :

> select 1 from pg_create_logical_replication_slot('pubqablankdb','pgoutput')
>
> create publication pubqablankdb for all tables

**Subscription Database:**

- Creating Subscription:

> CREATE SUBSCRIPTION subqablankdb CONNECTION 'host=1.1.1.1 port=5432 user=postgres password=xxxxx dbname=qablankdb' PUBLICATION pubqablankdb  with (create_slot= false,slot_name  = 'pubqablankdb', enabled  = true);

Please see below the database info. (**UTF8 encoding**)

```
Master DB: qablankdb
Replica DB: auditlog
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add more info about how your replication is configured?  It seems the same problem as [Logical Replication and Character encoding](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AT5PR84MB0084FAE5976D89CDE9733093EE4A0%40AT5PR84MB0084.NAMPRD84.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM) )

Comment: Added replication configured steps

Comment: I was hoping to see the info on the character encoding of the two involved databases.....

Comment: We're using UTF8 encoding for both the database. Please see the updated question.